# How to convert this wcf basic binding to a custom binding?

Tags: wcf

How to convert this wcf basic binding to a custom binding ??

```
      <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAutenticacion" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Thanks advance!

Comment: what kind of custom binding? what is custom about it?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the online wcf binding converter http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2009/08/bindingbox-convert-wcf-bindings.html

EDIT: when you use [this service](http://webservices20.cloudapp.net/default.aspx) remember to hace a  tag before the  (as in the default sample there). Then the result will be:

```
<!-- generated via Yaron Naveh's http://webservices20.blogspot.com/ -->

<customBinding>
  <binding name="NewBinding0">
    <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" requireDerivedKeys="false" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" />
    <textMessageEncoding MessageVersion="Soap11" />
    <httpsTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>

<!-- generated via Yaron Naveh's http://webservices20.blogspot.com/ -->
```

EDIT: this is how you create this binding from code:

```
        var b = new CustomBinding();
        var s = SecurityBindingElement.CreateCertificateOverTransportBindingElement(
            MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10);
        s.SetKeyDerivation(false);
        s.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;

        b.Elements.Add(s);
        b.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement() {  MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11});
        b.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());
```

when you create your client you can set certificates like this:

```
c.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but, I did that before and the service is returning a "Bad Request" =(

Comment: Okay, I am generating the correct request now, but, I need to do the same programatically, because I dont have the private key, the private key is stored in a HSM Device, so, To be able to consume the service, I need to the same programatically... I find out some C# code from msdn, but the code is too complex to me.. the samples from msdn "WF_WCF_Samples" has some projects to create custom tokens but I dont understand at all... I dont know what to do... :(

Comment: Yaron, I did that too but I dont have the private key (RSA) I hace the certificate only =(

Comment: In this case you cannot use certificateovertransport. This mode requires a client certificate for signature

Comment: this is not a technical issue - this is something more essential. doing  certificateovertransport w/o having private certificate is like using username and password without knowing the username. this is not possible. maybe you do not need certificateovertransport  but something else?